# How to export a type in a named export in Typescript

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces, software-design

I have a set of `const` and types that I have to export and I would like to export them under a named export. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to export types under a named export since they always have to be exported directly. In the meantime, I resorted to namespaces but they're already deprecated and I wanted to organize my code with native modules.

Ideally, this is what I would like to happen but types can't be used as a property of an object:

```js
const departments = ['BIR', 'CENRO'] as const
const difficulties = ['Hard', 'Very Hard', 'Super Hard'] as const
const statuses = ['Queued', 'Ongoing', 'Transferred'] as const

const schema = { /* ... */ }

type Department = typeof departments[number]
type Difficulty = typeof difficulties[number]
type Status = typeof statuses[number]

// Assume types can be included as a property
export const LandLot = {
  schema,
  Processing: {
    departments, difficulties, statuses,
    Department, Difficulty, Status
  }
}
```

Using namespaces, I temporarily resorted to this:

```js
const departments = ['BIR', 'CENRO'] as const
const difficulties = ['Hard', 'Very Hard', 'Super Hard'] as const
const statuses = ['Queued', 'Ongoing', 'Transferred'] as const

const schema = { /* ... */ }

export declare namespace LandLot {
  export namespace Processing {
    type Department = typeof departments[number]
    type Difficulty = typeof difficulties[number]
    type Status = typeof statuses[number]   
  }
}

export const LandLot = {
  schema,
  Processing: {
    departments, difficulties, statuses
  }
}
```

Without using namespaces, I'd have to prepend `LandLot_Processing_` to all the types which looks so ugly:

```js
const departments = ['BIR', 'CENRO'] as const
const difficulties = ['Hard', 'Very Hard', 'Super Hard'] as const
const statuses = ['Queued', 'Ongoing', 'Transferred'] as const

const schema = { /* ... */ }

export type LandLot_Processing_Department = typeof departments[number]
export type LandLot_Processing_Difficulty = typeof difficulties[number]
export type LandLot_Processing_Status = typeof statuses[number]

export const LandLot = {
  schema,
  Processing: {
    departments, difficulties, statuses
  }
}
```

Comment: It may help if you also gave any error messages in your post...  Perhaps searching on those might also shed some light on a solution.

Comment: Hello @JGFMK, well there aren't any errors to begin with

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to export them under a named export.

Namespaces are indeed the right tool for this. That is what I would do.